# SwiftUI NavigationLink with constant binding for isActive

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I don't understand why `SwiftUI` `NavigationLink`'s `isActive` behaves as if it has it's own state. Even though I pass a constant to it, the back button overrides the value of the binding once pressed.

Code:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationLinkPlayground: View {

    @State
    var active = true

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Navigation Link playground")
                Button(action: { active.toggle() }) {
                    Text("Toggle")
                }

                Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 40)

                FixedNavigator(active: active)
            }
        }
    }

}

fileprivate struct FixedNavigator: View {

    var active: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("Fixed navigator is active: \(active)" as String)

            NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondScreen(),
                    // this is technically a constant!
                    isActive: Binding(
                            get: { active },
                            set: { newActive in print("User is setting to \(newActive), but we don't let them!") }
                    ),
                    label: { Text("Go to second screen") }
            )
        }
    }

}

fileprivate struct SecondScreen: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Nothing to see here")
    }

}
```

[image]

---

This is a minimum reproducible example, my actual intention is to handle the back button press manually. So when the `set` inside the `Binding` is called, I want to be able to decide when to actually proceed. (So like based on some validation or something.)

And I don't understand what is going in and why the back button is able to override a constant binding.

Comment: NavigationLink is one-way directional, back button belongs to and managed by NavigationView, not by link. We don't have control over it (at least for now) - create custom back button if you want to manage it.

Comment: I still cannot understand why the binding's constant value does not override if the link is active or not. I thought using a constant set to `true` would prevent back navigation altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `isActive` is wrong. `isActive` takes a binding boolean and whenever you set that binding boolean to `true`, the navigation link gets activated and you are navigated to the destination.
`isActive` **does not** control whether the navigation link is clickable/disbaled or not.
Here's an example of correct use of `isActive`. You can manually trigger the navigation to your second view by setting `activateNavigationLink` to `true`.

#### EDIT 1:

In this new sample code, you can disable and enable the back button at will as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var activateNavigationLink = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // This isn't visible and should take 0 space from the screen!
                // Because its `label` is an `EmptyView`
                // It'll get programmatically triggered when you set `activateNavigationLink` to `true`.
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondScreen(),
                    isActive: $activateNavigationLink,
                    label: EmptyView.init
                )
                
                Text("Fixed navigator is active: \(activateNavigationLink)" as String)
                
                Button("Go to second screen") {
                    activateNavigationLink = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct SecondScreen: View {
    
    @State var backButtonActivated = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Nothing to see here")
            
            Button("Back button is visible: \(backButtonActivated)" as String) {
                backButtonActivated.toggle()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(!backButtonActivated)
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is that `isActive` does not control the current state of the `NavigationLink`, because it can be overridden once the back is pressed. I didn't mention the enabled / disabled part, I just wanted to show how it works.

Comment: I know you can trigger the navigation, the unexpected thing to me was that you cannot prevent it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, let me see if i can find something to solve that.

Comment: does this answer your question or im still off?

Comment: Well, the back button should always be there, should register clicks but it should ultimately be me who decides to procees or not

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you want the back button to be there and be clickable but not work unless you enable it to work? What would be the point of a back button that doesnt work?! im not sure if thats even doable using UIKit. you can workaround it though, for example showing a button with title "back button is disabled" when you hide the back button.

Comment: Imagine a scebario where an alert is presented to the user if they really want to go back or something like that

Comment: you can change `backButtonActivated` to true at will to enable the back button again. Also you can self-dismiss the view using this method: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-view-dismiss-itself

Comment: Thanks, I think these will cover my cases

Comment: I would't mind an upvote / answer acceptance if you saw my answer worthy and it solved your problem :)